# MS SQL count values for per row for per id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count incident types per depot. My current query returns the following result set:

[image]

I then apply a count query on this set which looks like this:

```
select middleList.DepotName as depot,
   count(middleList.NearMiss) as NearMiss,
   count(middleList.Theft) as Theft,
   count(middleList.Security) as Security,
   count(middleList.LostTimeDisablingInjury) as LostTimeDisablingInjury,
   count(middleList.Fire) as Fire,
   count(middleList.OccupationalIllness) as OccupationalIllness,
   count(middleList.VehicleAccident) as LostTimeDisablingInjury,
   count(middleList.Spliiage) as Fire,
   count(middleList.PropertyDamage) as OccupationalIllness,
   count(middleList.NonConformance) as NonConformance,
   count(middleList.Other) as Other

   from 
       (SELECT     dbo.IncidentTypes.NearMiss, dbo.IncidentTypes.Theft, 
       dbo.IncidentTypes.Security, dbo.IncidentTypes.LostTimeDisablingInjury, 
       dbo.IncidentTypes.Fire, dbo.IncidentTypes.OccupationalIllness, 
                     dbo.IncidentTypes.VehicleAccident, dbo.IncidentTypes.Spliiage, 
       dbo.IncidentTypes.PropertyDamage, dbo.IncidentTypes.NonConformance, 
       dbo.IncidentTypes.Other, dbo.Incidents.IncidentTitle, dbo.Depots.DepotName, 
       dbo.Incidents.IncidentNumber
       FROM            dbo.Departments INNER JOIN
                       dbo.Depots ON dbo.Departments.DepotId = dbo.Depots.DepotId 
       INNER JOIN
                       dbo.Employees ON dbo.Departments.DepartmentId = 
                       dbo.Employees.DepartmentId INNER JOIN
                       dbo.IncidentTypes INNER JOIN
                       dbo.Incidents ON dbo.IncidentTypes.IncidentTypeId = 
                       dbo.Incidents.IncidentTypeId ON dbo.Employees.EmployeeId = 
                       dbo.Incidents.EmployeeId_EmployeeInvolv             
       Where Incidents.DateCreated = (SELECT MAX (i2.DateCreated) FROM 
       Incidents as i2 WHERE Incidents.IncidentNumber = i2.IncidentNumber)) as 
       middleList

   group by middleList.DepotName
```

Which return the following incorrect results:
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the problem.

It seems like the rows are being counted and not the actual values, thus adding this to the count insured that they were being counted properly:

```
count(case when middleList.NearMiss <> '0' then 0 end  ) as NearMiss
```

End result being:

[image]